# Outdoor 50 amp 4-wire Outlet Install

Tags: electrical, receptacle, installation

[image]I want to install an outlet for outdoor connection of an RV. However, the location of the service entrance box is close to a inside corner of the exterior of the house so the easiest location is on the same external wall as the service box and will require a hole through the brick wall near the service entrance entry conduit. The outlet would have to be in close quarters since the wall is only about 2 feet wide so the entrance conduit goes perpendicular at the center of the wall plus other wires and entries are in the same area. I want to run the outlet wire out through the brick about half way between the conduit and the corner directly into an external surface mounted box with a 120 volt outdoor circuit for utility purposes on a separate wire passed through the same conduit through the 220 box to the 120 box. 
Is there anything questionable or incorrect about that installation method, or something I should be concerned about with it?

Comment: The service box is inside the garage and the external wall is opposite the box on the outside of course.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the service entrance box?

Comment: I haven't figured out how to put pictures into this site yet. I don't see what the panel has to do with it - what are  you looking for? The panel is about 24" tall and has about 6 double-wide locations open for the narrow GE circuit breakers. It takes up most of the width with a panel, but all I have to do is find a place where I can drill through the bricks either above or below or possibly along side the box for the wires to go into the conduit to the outside surface box. There should be enough room. Not sure what I can show you with a picture. uses thqp cbs has 4cbs ganged markd 200 as main

Comment: You should be able to hit "edit" in "share edit ...." on your post then use the icon that looks like some sort of stylized painting to add pictures to it

Comment: how's that - a little large eh

Answer (score 1):

### You're on the right track

Since you have a suitable panel, and enough spare space in it, I would go for what you describe, using 3 6AWG wires for the 50A/240V circuit and 2 12AWG wires for the 120V circuit (as well as a 10AWG ground, if you're in plastic conduit that is).  You'll want to use a GFCI breaker at the panel for the outdoor 120V circuit, by the way, as that keeps it safe from the weather, vs a GFCI receptacle outside which can get affected by water that leaks into the receptacle box.

If you're going to do this using cables, then you can use 8/3 on a 40A circuit or 6/3 on a 50A circuit for the 240V receptacle, with a 12/2 extending into the 240V receptacle's box and spliced there to some 12/2 UF or two 12AWG THWNs in conduit to connect to the 120V receptacle.

Comment: I have an outdoor surface mount 4x4 box with sealed cover. I prefer plastic and I also have a short piece of 4-wire #8 cable and some #12 uf for the 120V. I could run the 120V to a separate box inside, install a GFCI outlet and then run from there to the outside 120V using a standard outlet, right? I can't figure out why they didn't locate an outlet nearer the door anyway.

Comment: Any pointers about drilling the hole through the brick? How do I locate the best place relative to the brick or does it matter?

Comment: @JayDubyah dunno on the brick thing, but you should use individual THWNs in conduit for this run instead of cables (and #8 is a smidge too small for a 50A receptacle as receptacle terminations are limited to 60degC)

Comment: No help that it is only a few feet long? I'll put a 40 A breaker on it

Comment: @JayDubyah is there a reason you are hard-copy dead-set on using the cable you have though? (is it NM or UF, for that matter?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92412/discussion-between-jaydubyah-and-threephaseeel).